# Partial match ignoring case and diacritics

Tags: java, unicode, internationalization

I have a list of sentences and need to check whether certain words are present inside it. I need to ignore case, accents, diacritics, ligatures, etc.

For instance, all of the following searches should return true:

- São Paulo contains SÃO
- Nürnberg contains Nurn
- Siauliai contains Š

I am aware of the java.text.Collator and java.text.Normalizer classes, but I couldn't find a way to do partial matches.

Comment: Using the normalizer to NKD-decompose letters into base letter and combining diacritics, you can remove the diacritics `replaceAll("\\p{M}", "");` and then all should be there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up using a combination of regex and java.text.Normalizer as suggested by joop-eggen:

```
public static final Pattern DIACRITICS_AND_MODIFIERS = Pattern.compile("[\\p{InCombiningDiacriticalMarks}\\p{IsLm}\\p{IsSk}]");

...

String text = Normalizer.normalize(input, Normalizer.Form.NFKD);
text = DIACRITICS_AND_MODIFIERS.matcher(text).replaceAll("").toLowerCase();
```

I used **NFKD** instead of **NKD** because it decomposes special cases like ligatures (**ﬃ**) roman numerals (**Ⅸ**) and superscripts (**⁵**). There are still a few corner cases that the above code misses (**Æ** and **ł** for instance), but those are not important in my Locale (Portuguese).

I then normalize both the search term and the text that is to be searched and use a **String.contains** to search it.

Comment: Showing the worked out code is appreciated. Will help others.